# Procedural natural stone wall in geonodes

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, instances

So im trying to make this pirate cave and im stuck on getting the walls/ceiling to look anywhere close to realistic stone. I tried to instance objects on a plane but got a result that looks both pretty blocky and also too blob shaped(there is also a remesh on this particular object).[image]

In the second attempt i tried to deform existing geometry by joining my improvised blockout and adding a bit of noise to it. That went even worse and seems to be very prone to errors due to the quality of the mesh, it doesn't look great either.

[image]

I was going for this sort of stone, pretty weathered and relatively sharp. If anyone has any idea how to achieve this general look, be that with geonodes or without I would really appreciate your input.
[image]

Comment: IMHO if you want to recreate these kinds of rock formations as is, you should study how they are formed. It's a very complex and lengthy process that takes hundreds of thousands of year. First the rock is formed under the crust of the earth with great temperatures, then it is ejected by tectonic powers on the surface of the earth. After that, there is thermal, rain, wind, waves etc. that cause erosion. And a bunch of other factors. Personally, i think a possible path to realism here would be a combination of what you already have as geometry and some clever texturing to make it more believable

Comment: For realism texture is essential ... any reason to use GN at all ... here is used just a texture on cylinder shape https://vimeo.com/user8735075